# swing client with netty

Tags: java, swing, netty

Does anyone have a java code example showing how to connect a java swing GUI to netty 3.2.7?

Currently the GUI I have sends a message to the server via a netty client class. The server response is correctly being received by the netty client handler (in the `messageReceived` method).

The question is what is the correct way of getting this response back to the GUI.

Of course the application has got many different GUI's which need to perform the same type of function - i.e. send message from java swing GUI, receive response in netty client handler (in `messageReceived` method), receive this message in the java swing GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Well It depends as there are more then one solution. One could be to inject a listener to the ChannelHandler which then will get notified once the message was received. An other solution could be to send events to a topic once a message was received and register the interested swing parts on the topic, so they get notified.

Comment: Do you have a code example I could look at so I can solve this? The message sent from the gui is always a java object. I receive a java object in the `messageReceived` method and need to return this object to the calling method / class.