# MVC front-end for netty client

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller, netty

I've adapted the Quote Of The Moment ([QOTM](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm)) a bit and would like to build a GUI front-end.  It's simple enough to pass objects from the `DatagramClientHandler` to the GUI.  However, it seems intractable for the GUI to reference the handler.

The `QuotesGUI` class extends JFrame to take advantage of the Netbeans drag-and-drop palette to add Swing components easily.  It's quite verbose.

Apparently, the solution is to:

> Well It depends as there are more then one solution. One could be to
>   inject a listener to the ChannelHandler which then will get notified
>   once the message was received. An other solution could be to send
>   events to a topic once a message was received and register the
>   interested swing parts on the topic, so they get notified.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780410/262852

DatagramClientHandler:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.netty;

import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.client.gui.QuotesGUI;

public class DatagramClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DatagramClientHandler.class.getName());
    private final QuotesGUI gui = new QuotesGUI();
    private volatile Channel channel = null;

    DatagramClientHandler() {
        log.info("starting..");
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

    private DatagramPacket getNext() {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                Unpooled.copiedBuffer("QOTM?", CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 4454));
        return packet;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg) throws Exception {
        String response = msg.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        log.info(response);
        gui.setQuote(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        log.severe(cause.toString());
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

sample method from the GUI.

```
public void setQuote(String packet) {
    text.setText(packet);
}
```

Comment: Separate your layers, the GUI should have no (real) knowledge of the handler.  It also employes that you breaching the single thread rules of Swing (updating the UI from outside the context of the EDT).  Instead, you could set up a listener `interface` which can respond to changes in the handler and make appropriate changes.  This could also be backed with a `SwingWorker`, which would allow the handler to work in a separate thread, but provides methods by which the UI can be updated/notified safely...

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, that's my question.  Just in pseudo code, would you elaborate?  Of course, I would like to separate the layers -- I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by separating your layers of responsibilities...

I would probably start by defining some kind of listener `interface` which can registered with an instance of `DatagramClientHandler`.  This `interface` would allow interested parties to be notified of changes or events within `DatagramClientHandler` and deal with those events as they see fit...

```
public interface MessageListener {
    public void quoteRecieved(SimpleChannelInboundHandler source, String quote);
    public void errorOccured(SimpleChannelInboundHandler source, Throwable cause);
}
```

Then you would need to provide support for the listener...

```
public class DatagramClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DatagramClientHandler.class.getName());
    //private final QuotesGUI gui = new QuotesGUI();
    private volatile Channel channel = null;
    private List<MessageListener> listeners;

    DatagramClientHandler() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<MessageListener>(25);
        //...
    }

    public synchronized void addMessageListener(MessageListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public synchronized void removeMessageListener(MessageListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected synchronized void fireQuoteRecieved(String quote) {
        for (MessageListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.quoteRecieved(this, quote);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg) throws Exception {
        String response = msg.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        log.info(response);
        fireQuoteRecieved(response);
    }

    //...etc...
```

Now, when you want to receive notifications, you would register an instance of `MessageListener` with an instance of `DatagramClientHandler`...

The problem you will have, is ensuring that any updates you make to the UI are carried out in the EDT correctly...

```
//...
public void quoteRecieved(SimpleChannelInboundHandler source, final String quote) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            text.setText(packet);
        }
    });
}
```

Now, if you really wanted to, you could further decouple the code with another `interface`...

```
public interface QuoteFactory {
    public synchronized void addMessageListener(MessageListener listener);
    public synchronized void removeMessageListener(MessageListener listener);
}
```

This would then be implemented by `DatagramClientHandler` and you UI would require an instance of `QuoteFactory` to be passed to it so that it could register interest in been notified when something happens...